# When loading Revit files in forge viewer, how to ignore True North rotation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We use the forge viewer to view different AEC models.
Most of them are Revit files, some of them have a true north rotation.
We want to aggregate different files using this approach https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7
with the 'AggregatedView'.
Can someone give me some pointer on how to load a Revit model and ignore the true North rotation?

Answer (score 1):

The `angleToTrueNorth` is read by the viewer from the model's metadata, and I'm afraid that there's no way of customizing that, other than perhaps modifying the value directly in Revit.

The value is converted into radians (`let angle = (Math.PI / 180.0) * metadata["angleToTrueNorth"];`) and the rotation is then applied to all model fragments. What you could try is customizing the `placementTransform` (also mentioned in the blog post) to revert the rotation.

Comment: Thanks @petr-broz, will try the placementTransform. How can I read the ["angleToTrueNorth"] metadata before the model is loaded in the viewer?

Comment: That's a good question. The Viewer APIs don't provide any helper for that I'm afraid, so you'd have to basically parse the metadata from the SVF assets in the Model Derivative service yourself, e.g., using this library: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils.

Comment: Maybe on a different note, why has the TrueNorth angle influence on the position of the geometry in forge?
In Revit if one project with a true north setting is linked into another project with a different (or 0 angle) true north, the true north angle is ignored and both project are positioned relative to each other in XYZ. 
When both projects are shown in Forge I get a different result (one is rotated)..